# sqlite3 can't find a record by attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have a strange little Rails problem.  Imagine an empty Invitation class inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base.  There is one Invitation in the sqlite3 database but ActiveRecord can't find it by its *token* attribute.  Follow along as we try to find it and see if you can figure out why.

```
0 urzatron work/sunrise % rails c                          
Loading development environment (Rails 3.1.0)

irb(main):001:0> Invitation.all
  Invitation Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "invitations".* FROM "invitations" 
=> [#<Invitation id: 1, accepted_at: nil, assignment_id: 1, contact: "dean@example.net", network: "email", sender_id: 1, sent_at: "2011-11-07 02:50:10", token: "41a673223a2b059b212ca3753896d3fd38e1d1dd">]

irb(main):002:0> Invitation.find_by_token "41a673223a2b059b212ca3753896d3fd38e1d1dd"
  Invitation Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "invitations".* FROM "invitations" WHERE "invitations"."token" = '41a673223a2b059b212ca3753896d3fd38e1d1dd' LIMIT 1
=> nil

irb(main):003:0> Invitation.find 1
  Invitation Load (82.7ms)  SELECT "invitations".* FROM "invitations" WHERE "invitations"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<Invitation id: 1, accepted_at: nil, assignment_id: 1, contact: "dean@example.net", network: "email", sender_id: 1, sent_at: "2011-11-07 02:50:10", token: "41a673223a2b059b212ca3753896d3fd38e1d1dd">

irb(main):004:0> Invitation.where( :token => "41a673223a2b059b212ca3753896d3fd38e1d1dd" ).first
  Invitation Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "invitations".* FROM "invitations" WHERE "invitations"."token" = '41a673223a2b059b212ca3753896d3fd38e1d1dd' LIMIT 1
=> nil
```

So, that's a little weird.

```
0 urzatron work/sunrise % rails dbconsole
SQLite version 3.7.5
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"

sqlite> select * from invitations;
1||1|dean@example.net|email|1|2011-11-07 02:50:10.818984|41a673223a2b059b212ca3753896d3fd38e1d1dd

sqlite> select * from invitations where token = "41a673223a2b059b212ca3753896d3fd38e1d1dd";

sqlite>
```

Here's the migration for the curious.

```
class CreateInvitations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :invitations do |t|
      t.datetime :accepted_at
      t.references :assignment
      t.string :contact, :null => false
      t.string :network, :null => false
      t.references :sender, :null => false
      t.datetime :sent_at
      t.string :token, :null => false
    end
    add_index :invitations, :accepted_at
    add_index :invitations, [:network,:token]
    add_index :invitations, :token
    add_column :users, :invitation_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: What does `select '-' || token || '-' from invitations` or `select length(token) from invitations` have to say from `rails dbconsole`?

Comment: `select '-' || token || '-' from invitations;` =>
**-41a673223a2b059b212ca3753896d3fd38e1d1dd-**
`select length(token) from invitations;` =>
 **40**
`select length("41a673223a2b059b212ca3753896d3fd38e1d1dd")` =>
**40**

Comment: So no stray spaces, SELECT with equality doesn't work, SELECT with LIKE *does* work? Hmmm.

Comment: Really, quite curious. `select * from invitations where token like "41a673223a2b059b212ca3753896d3fd38e1d1dd";` **1||1|dean@example.net|email|1|2011-11-07 02:50:10.818984|41a673223a2b059b212ca3753896d3fd38e1d1dd**

Comment: Any chance that you could share the SQLite database file?

Comment: I'd like to share the data.  In order to do so, I decided to drop the other tables.  After doing so, with only the one *invitations* table, the select started working.  Gonna see if it's a particular table.

Comment: Here it is in all its brokenness [http://deanandadie.net/tmp/development.sqlite3](http://deanandadie.net/tmp/development.sqlite3)

Comment: Bizarre. `select * from invitations where token || 'x' = '03a91af314d27f74c55e9c88b7e5287c15771c08' || 'x'` works as expected, manually updating the token via SQL to `'03a91....'` makes it work fine. I wonder if some of the looseness in SQLite's type system is getting confused by the leading digit. Or your database file is corrupted. Or I need to drink more until things make sense :)

Comment: I went down a similar path.  Seems that generating my tokens starting with a character fixes the problem.  Is `select` broken? (-:

Comment: I think something funny is going on with the Rails/SQLite interaction. If I do an UPDATE in the SQLite shell to set `token='03a91af314d27f74c55e9c88b7e5287c15771c08'`, everything works as expected and I don't have to drink reality into making sense.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same bug (I think). I generated my tokens with `SecureRandom.hex(8)` and couldn't do a *find_by_token*.

If I replace the token generation by `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(8)`, the bug is fixed.

See https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/issues/19 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

So, it's 1 of 2 things:

1. Strings are automatically being truncated by sqlite for some reason
2. Token is a reserved word in Rails 3.1 and it's just undocumented (yet)

Comment: It's not reason 1. I have another model with an attribute named "token" and that's working fine.

Comment: And it's not reason 2:
sqlite> select * from invitations where token like "41a673223a2b059b212ca3753896d3fd38e1d1dd";

1||1|dean@example.net|email|1|2011-11-07 02:50:10.818984|41a673223a2b059b212ca3753896d3fd38e1d1dd

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue just yesterday, and it turned out that changing the 'token' type to a string instead of text.  Once I did this, SQLite3 was then able to make the select properly.

So in the migration (or alter if you will), I hadn't released yet, so I just re-migrated:

```
t.text :token
```

would change to

```
t.string :token
```

All the best.